# main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Sort.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, make, cmake

I want to write makefile to compile my C++ codes.

The tree of my files is this:

```
.
├── include
│   └── Sort.h
├── lib
│   └── Sort.cpp
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── makefile
    └── obj
```

And this is my makefile:

```
cc=g++
CFLAGS= -c -w

.PHONY: all clean

all: main

main: main.o Sort.o
    $(cc) main.o Sort.o -o Sort -l m 

Sort.o: Sort.cpp ../lib
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp 


main.o: main.cpp ../include/Sort.h
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp 

clean: 
    rm *.o main
```

But I give this error after run `make` in terminal:

```
g++ -c -w main.cpp 
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: Sort.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <Sort.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:16: main.o] Error 1
```

Can you help me to edit my makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @steeldriver comment.

This is the right makefile:

```
cc=g++
CFLAGS= -c -w -I../include

.PHONY: all clean

all: main

main: main.o Sort.o
    $(cc) main.o Sort.o -o Sort -l m 

Sort.o: ../lib/Sort.cpp ../include/Sort.h
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) ../lib/Sort.cpp 


main.o: main.cpp ../include/Sort.h Sort.o
    $(cc) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp 

clean: 
    rm *.o main
```